# Hide Div depending on a databound value on UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, event-handling

I've inherited the maintenance of an ASP.NET Application and now have to develop a feature which is bending my mind a little bit although I know the answer must be simple, for now this answer is eluding me..

So I have a Repeater Controls inside a UserControl. To this repeater the data is bound on code-behind and then is displayed on the Repeater's Child Item accordingly.
Every time an Item is Bound on the code-behind there's a function executing which I'm not really understanding what it is doing.

This is the asp.net code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocumentsForCategory" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 0px 10px;">
            <a target="_blank" href='<%#EncoderService.HtmlAttributeEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentUrl") as string)%>'><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%#EncoderService.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentName") as string)%>'></asp:Literal></a>                                
            <%if (Mode == Curriculum.BLL.ControlMode.Edit)
              { %>                                
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" Height="10px" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/edit.png" ToolTip='<%$Resources:Main,Dialog_Title_UpdateWorkDocument%>' CommandName="EditItem" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DocumentId")%>' runat="server" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" Height="10px" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowConfirmationPopup();" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/delete.png" ToolTip='<%$Resources:Main,DeleteDocument%>' CommandName="DeleteItem" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DocumentId")%>' runat="server" />
            <%} %>
            <div class="ViewWorkDocumentsFileData">
                <%--<asp:Literal ID="LtDocDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Utilities.FormatDateTimeToDisplay(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentDate"))%>'></asp:Literal>--%>
                <asp:Literal ID="LtDocSize" runat="server" Text='<%#Utilities.ConvertBytesToKilobytes((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentSize"))%>'></asp:Literal> Kb &nbsp|&nbsp                                    
                <asp:Literal ID="LtDocExt" runat="server" Text='<%#EncoderService.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentExtension") as string)%>'></asp:Literal>
                <div ID="DocumentCreationInfoPanel" runat="server" >
                    <asp:Literal ID="LtCreatedByLabel" runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:Main,CreatedBy_Label%>'></asp:Literal>
                    <asp:Literal ID="LtDocModification" runat="server" Text='<%#EncoderService.HtmlEncode(Curriculum.DataAccess.Membership.Users.GetUserDiplayNameForUsername(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentCreatedBy") as string))%>'></asp:Literal>&nbsp|&nbsp
                    <asp:Literal ID="LtDocDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Utilities.FormatDateTimeToDisplay(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentDate"))%>'></asp:Literal>
                 </div>
                 <div ID="DocumentModifiedInfoPanel" runat="server"  >
                    <asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedByLabel" runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:Main,ModifiedBy_Label%>'></asp:Literal>
                    <%--<asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedBy" runat="server" Text='<%#EncoderService.HtmlEncode((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedBy") != DBNull.Value) ? Curriculum.DataAccess.Membership.Users.GetUserDiplayNameForUsername(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedBy") as string) : HideDocumentsDetailInfo(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedBy")))%>'></asp:Literal>--%><%--&nbsp|&nbsp--%>
                     <asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedBy" runat="server" Text='<%#EncoderService.HtmlEncode(Curriculum.DataAccess.Membership.Users.GetUserDiplayNameForUsername(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedBy") as string))%>'></asp:Literal>&nbsp|&nbsp
                    <%--<asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:Main,ModifiedDate_Label%>'></asp:Literal>--%>
                    <%--<asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Utilities.FormatDateTimeToDisplay(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedDate") as string) %>'></asp:Literal>--%>
                    <asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Utilities.FormatDateTimeToDisplay(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedDate")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                </div>
            </div>                                
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div></div>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, most of the code was already there. What I did add here was the code inside the DocumentModifiedInfoPanel to show the modification date and user to that portion of the page (it's related to "annexed" documents).
Now if I don't have a modified date, that div should be hidden (it can still render, but remain invisible) and I'm not being able to accomplish that.

Here's my (relevant) code-behind:

```
protected void rptDocCategories_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
    {
        Repeater rptDocumentsForCategory = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptDocumentsForCategory");
        rptDocumentsForCategory.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(rptDocumentsForCategory_ItemCommand);
    }
}

protected void rptDocCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
    {
        Literal LtDocCategoryId = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("LtDocCategoryId");
        Repeater rptDocumentsForCategory = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptDocumentsForCategory");
        var ds = WorksDocumentCategories.GetDocumentsForCategoryAndWork(WorkId, int.Parse(LtDocCategoryId.Text));
        rptDocumentsForCategory.DataSource = ds;
        rptDocumentsForCategory.DataBind();

    }
}

public string HideDocumentsDetailInfo(object DBValue)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptDocCategories.Items)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)Utilities.Utilities.FindControlRecursive(item, "DocumentModifiedInfoPanel");
        if (div.ID == "DocumentModifiedInfoPanel" && DBValue == DBNull.Value)
        {
            div.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
        }
    }
     return "";
}
```

Now, the `HideDocumentsDetailInfo` method was written by me. You can try to see me using it on the first commented line inside the `DocumentModifiedInfoPanel`.
This approach almost works, but the last item on the annexed documents list will always show the div with an "empty" modification date instead of hdding it.

I've also noticed that the `rptDocCategories_ItemDataBound` method executes AFTER my own `HideDocumentsDetailInfo` and I suspect that that might be the reason why I'm not being able to hide the last item on the "list" of items to hide.

As a final note, I'm kinda lost if and how I can do that within the ItemDataBound event since I'm not seeing a way of accessing the properties value.

Any thoughts on this please?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Well, it actualy wasn't a tag but rather how I'm trying to do it, but given the similarity, I guess that is acceptable

Comment: It felt more like metadata than data, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually found a way around those problems with a really simple solution (which honestly, I don't know why I didn't thought of it earlier).

The answer here is to capture the `OnDataBinding` event for the `LtModifiedDate` Literal control.

```
<asp:Literal ID="LtModifiedDate" runat="server" OnDataBinding="LtModifiedDate_DataBinding" Text='<%# Utilities.FormatDateTimeToDisplay(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentModifiedDate")) %>'></asp:Literal>
```

With this, all I had to do was evaluate the date, and if it is `DateTime.MinValue` I just go ahead and set the `Visible` property (which I added) on the `DocumentModifiedInfoPanel` div, defined to true by default.

```
protected void LtModifiedDate_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Cast the sender to it's type
    Literal lit = (Literal)sender;

    //Convert the DateTime Text value to a DateTime
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(lit.Text);

    if (dt == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        //Cast the parent control (the div) to a HtmlGenericControl
        HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)lit.Parent;

        //Set the visible property to false
        div.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Simple as that!